# beautifulsoup4 get href from anchor element with specific attribute value

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the href value from multiple anchor elements on a page that have the attribute `itemprop` with value `url` using BeautifulSoup4

For example, extracting `/pages/page` from `<a itemprop="url" href="/pages/page"></a>` but there is multiple of these items in one page so I'd like them in an array.

I'm thinking something like this `soup("span", html = True, {'itemprop' : 'name' })`

Comment: did you try `find_all()` ? show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Via [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) you can search your parsed output for a specific tag. In your case it is quite easy. If the first parameter is a string, it'll only find the tags with that name. So `soup.find_all("a")` will find all anchor tags.

Now it also supports (almost) any keyword argument to further narrow down your selection. In your case you want the attribute `itemprop` to be set to `url` so you can do just that with `soup.find_all("a", itemprop="url")`.

That will now return you a list of tags, and if you want to extract the `href` attribute from those tags you can use `tag.get("href")`. The end result will be something like this:

```
anchored_tags = [tag.get("href") for tag in soup.find_all("a", itemprop="url")]
```